# What do the satellite dish and colored birds do?

Tags: celeste

Midway through Chapter 1 (*Forsaken City*), there’s a hidden satellite dish with a monitor flashing different colors. Nearby there are five multi-colored birds flying around. Every few seconds, the birds come together in a circle before dashing away from each other.

Is there some way to interact with the satellite dish and colored birds?

[image: Satellite dish with birds]

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You cannot *directly* interact with them, but they are important:

Hint 1:

> Note the pattern of the colors flashing on the screen and on the tip of the satellite. The pattern is White, Purple, Blue, Red, Purple, Yellow. These colors refer to the colors of the birds.

Hint 2:

> Now notice the positions of the birds relative to the center point after they spread apart, and refer back to the order of the colors on the screen.

Solution:

> The birds are in positions Up (white), Up-Right (red), Down-Right (blue), Left (purple), and Up-Left (yellow). The color pattern on the screen tells you the order to put these together, so the order of these directions is Up, Left, Down-Right, Up-Right, Left, Up-Left. If you perform dashes in this order, the Crystal Heart for chapter 1 will appear.